# No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONArray with JAVA Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

On my JAVA spring boot project I try to send a JSONArray but when I make the request with postman I have the error below:

"message": "No converter found for return value of type: class org.json.JSONArray"

Here is my code :

```
public ResponseEntity<JSONArray> getDiscussions(Authentication authentication) {
    Iterable<Discussion> discussions = discussionRepository.findAllDiscussion(authentication.getName());
    ObjectNode jsonObject = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

    for (Discussion discussion : discussions)
    {
        jsonObject.put("username", discussion.getUserFriend().getUsername());
        jsonObject.put("photoPath", discussion.getUserFriend().getPhotoPath());
        ja.put(jsonObject);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<JSONArray>(ja, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code:

```
package com.example.springjsonarray;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreetingController.class);

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public ResponseEntity<?> greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject();
        jo1.put("username", "Jhon");
        jo1.put("photoPath", "Doe");
        ja.put(jo1);

        JSONObject jo2 = new JSONObject();
        jo2.put("username", "Carol");
        jo2.put("photoPath", "Doe");
        ja.put(jo2);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(ja.toString());
    }
}
```

And response is:

```
[{"photoPath":"Doe","username":"Jhon"},{"photoPath":"Doe","username":"Carol"}]
```